# Adaptive card column sizing not working in bot framework c#

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I want to have 2 columns with 1st column having width 20% and other column to have width 80%, but it seems the size property is not getting applied to bot framework 3.0 in Microsoft Teams adaptive card. Below is the response i'm getting but still its getting divided on 50-50% size blocks.

````
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "0.5",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ColumnSet",
      "columns": [
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "size": 1,
          "items": [
            { "type": "Image",
              "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3647943215/d7f12830b3c17a5a9e4afcc370e3a37e_400x400.jpeg",
              "size": "small",
              "style": "person"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Column",
          "width": 5,
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "text": "Matt Hidinger",
              "weight": "bolder",
              "wrap": true
            },
            {
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "spacing": "none",
              "text": "Created {{DATE(2017-02-14T06:08:39Z, SHORT)}}",
              "isSubtle": true,
              "wrap": true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "Submit"
    }
  ]
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

The first column is (incorrectly) using a `size` property, but it should be `width`

This should achieve a 20/80 weight

```
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "ColumnSet",
            "columns": [
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 20,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "Image",
                            "url": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3647943215/d7f12830b3c17a5a9e4afcc370e3a37e_400x400.jpeg",
                            "size": "Small",
                            "style": "Person"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "type": "Column",
                    "width": 80,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": "Matt Hidinger",
                            "weight": "Bolder",
                            "wrap": true
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "spacing": "None",
                            "text": "Created {{DATE(2017-02-14T06:08:39Z, SHORT)}}",
                            "isSubtle": true,
                            "wrap": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.Submit",
            "title": "Submit"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: i'm unable to use "Width" property, its giving error as "Property doesn't exist", i'm using bot framework 3.0 with Microsoft.AdaptiveCard v0.5.

Comment: Could you please try updating the adaptive card version to the latest one and see if that helps?